# php DOMDocument->getElementById->nodeValue sripping html

Tags: php, html, domdocument, replace, html-entities

I am using php's `DOMDocument->getElementById->nodeValue` to set a particular DOM element's HTML. The problem is that the string is converted to HTML entities:
eg:
`nodeValue = html_entity_decode('<b>test</b>');` should output 'test' but instead it outputs '`&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;`'

Any ideas why? This happens even if i don't use the html_entity_decode function

Here is my updated script...which is NOW working:

```
// Construct a DOM object for updating the affected node
$html = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8"); 
if (!$html) return FALSE;

// Load the HTML file in question
$loaded = $html->loadHTMLFile($data['page_path']);
if (!$loaded)
{
    print 'Failed to load file';
    return FALSE;
}

// Establish the node being updated within the file
foreach ($data['divids'] as $divid)
{
    $element = $html->getElementById($divid);
    if (is_null($element))
    {
        print 'Failed to get existing element';
        return FALSE;
    }

    $newelement = $html->createElement('div');
    if (is_null($newelement))
    {
        print 'Failed to create new element';
        return FALSE;
    }
    $newelement->setAttribute('id', $divid);
    $newelement->setAttribute('class', 'reusable-block');

    // Perform the replacement
    $newelement->nodeValue = $replacement;
    $parent = $element->parentNode;
    $parent->replaceChild($newelement, $element);

    // Save the file back to its location
    $saved = $html->saveHTMLFile($data['page_path']);
    if (!$saved)
    {
        print 'Failed to save file';
        return FALSE;
    }
}

// Replace HTML entities left over
$content = files::readFile($data['page_path']);
$content = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $content);
$content = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $content);
if (!@fwrite($handle, $content))
{
    print 'Failed to replace entities';
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proper behavior - your  tag is being converted to a string, and strings in XML can't contain angle brackets (only tags can). Try converting the HTML into a DOMNode and appending it instead:

```
$node = $mydoc->createElement("b");
$node->nodeValue = "test";
$mydoc->getElementById("whatever")->appendChild($node);
```

**Update with working example:**

```
$html = '<html>
    <body id="myBody">
        <b id="myBTag">my old element</b>
    </body>
</html>';

$mydoc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$mydoc->loadXML($html);

// need to do this to get getElementById() to work
$all_tags = $mydoc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName("*");
foreach ($all_tags as $element) {
    $element->setIdAttribute("id", true);
}

$current_b_tag = $mydoc->getElementById("myBTag");
$new_b_tag = $mydoc->createElement("b");
$new_b_tag->nodeValue = "my new element";
$result = $mydoc->getElementById("myBody");
$result->replaceChild($new_b_tag, $current_b_tag);

echo $mydoc->saveXML($mydoc->documentElement);
```

Comment: The issue is that I'm replacing the element...not appending it. Sadly

Comment: Then the removeChild() and replaceChild() methods may be of interest: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Comment: Doing it this way also converts the HTML to entities...oddly

Comment: I've updated my post with an example of how to replace a node with another node. This will work with nodes only, not mixed nodes & text. In that case, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598829/xml-node-with-mixed-content-using-php-dom

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will review this soon. Being a developer lends itself to being swamped...

Comment: I updated my script to match what you suggest seems to work but it's throwing an error, 'Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'' in the line that reads: "$html->replaceChild($newelement, $element);"

Comment: replaceChild() is not a DOMDocument method, it's a DOMNode method - you need to call it on the parent node of the node to be replaced.

Comment: I should mention, my document is not XML. It is pure HTML

Comment: As long as DOMDocument->loadHTMLFile() can parse it, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback once again!
I updated my script which is now working however, I'm back at square one again because the the HTML is being converted into HTML entities.